# iOS Crash report is unsymbolicated

Tags: ios, parse-platform, crash-reports

Although, I have run the script to upload .dsym file, it shows this error: "This stack trace is unsymbolicated. To obtain symbols, you need to upload your dSYM file via the command line tool."

Also, even if I force a crash using the method provided, it does not show up under analytics. I am on ParseCrashReporting 1.9.2.

It used to work reliably earlier, about 3-4 months back. Not any more.

Comment: What do you want to know?

Comment: :+1: Submitted a related issue to FB Bug Tracking system https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/503791233122986/

Comment: I want to know if it is a reported problem or if I am doing anything wrong that symbols are not showing on Parse Crash reports